# Python program that uploads image to telegra.ph

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, image, python-requests

I tried to write the code using requests and some help from a github page but I couldn't succeed.

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("You must specify a file name.")
    sys.exit(-1)
filePath = sys.argv[1]


with open(filePath , 'rb') as f:
    print(
        requests.post(
            'http://telegra.ph/upload',
            files={'file': ('file', f, 'image/jpeg')}  # image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, video/mp4
        ).json()
    )
```

It gives me the following error `{'error': 'No files passed'}`

Comment: could you mark my answer please.

Comment: thanks, I love the points <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution, Hope this helps.

```py
import requests
import sys

# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("You must specify a file name.")
        sys.exit(-1)
    filePath = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as f:
        # Upload File
        json_data = requests.post('https://telegra.ph/upload', files={'file': ('file', f, 'image/jpeg')}).json() # image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, video/mp4
        # get file URL
        filename = "https://telegra.ph" + json_data[0]['src']
        print(filename)
```

## usage

```sh
C:\Projects\other>python test.py "C:\Projects\other\test.jpg"
https://telegra.ph/file/cb0f19a99be9c35bf6ae1.jpg

C:\Projects\other>
```